# Make either x or y attribute required in form

Tags: django, django-forms

How do I make either first or second attribute required in form?

In this form, I want user to fill either `text_to_translate` or `file`.
I've tried to create `clean_something` for both attributes but it seems not working. It raises -

> KeyError Exception Value: 'file'

It's probably because when the `clean_text_to_translate` method is called, the `file` is not cleaned yet.

Do you know what to do?

```
class NewOrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text_to_translate = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Specification'}), required=False)
    file = forms.FileField(required=False)
    delivery_date = forms.DateField(label='Deadline', widget=SelectDateWidget(years=[y for y in range(1930, 2050)]))

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = (
            'short_description', 'language_from', 'text_to_translate', 'file', 'notes','style', 'delivery_date',
        )
        widgets = {
            'text_to_translate': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'language_from': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'dropdown'})
            # 'level':forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

        }


    def clean_text_to_translate(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['file'] is None:
            return self.cleaned_data['file']
        return ValidationError('You can fill either text to translate or attach a file')

    def clean_file(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['text_to_translate']=='':
            return self.cleaned_data['text_to_translate']
        return ValidationError('You can fill either text to translate or attach a file')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are validating two fields which depend on each other - this is described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other). The docs recommend to do the validation in the form's clean() method:

> We are performing validation on more than one field at a time, so the form’s clean() method is a good spot to do this.

At this moment you have available all the values that survived the individual fields' validation - so remember that `text_to_translate` and `file` may be empty - don't access these values using square bracket notation, use `cleaned_data.get()` instead. Your clean() method might look like that:

```
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(NewOrderForm, self).clean()
        file = cleaned_data.get("file")
        text_to_translate = cleaned_data.get("text_to_translate")
        if file and text_to_translate:  # both fields were filled
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must provide either text or file, not both.")
        elif not (file or text_to_translate)  # neither one was filled
            raise forms.ValidationError("You must provide either text or file")
```

of course, you'll need to display that error using `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` in your template.

Comment: Thank you, I understand your suggestion and will use it, but there is a little mistake probably. I meant xor - one and only one of the two fields should be filled.